# What Android version can I install on Samsung Galaxy S3 safely?

Tags: rooting, samsung, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3

My old Samsung S3 is getting sluggish. Really sluggish. I want to know which version of Android I can install on it? I cannot find on Samsung's web site some kind of reference table that says which OS version can be installed on which phone.

I have found a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=791SHbuO6pc) video showing Lollipop installed on S3. Should I do that?

Comment: The S3 official last update, I think,  is Android 4.3. Any other greater versions are custom ROMs. Custom ROMs have their pros and cons.

Comment: Hi @esQmo_  I am new to android (as you can see from my question). So, please let me know why I should NOT install a newer Android version. I mean at this moment my phone really really really sucks (slow). So, what is better to buy a new phone or (try to) install a new OS ?

Comment: This question is opinion based and may be too broad. Android Enthusiasts prohibits such questions. But to answer to your question the lag may be a software issue or even a hardware issue. Sometimes flashing can solve this or a simple factory reset. Custom ROMs exist because manufacturers decide to not make an update to a newer android version due to hardware limitations or because they want you buy a new model etc...

Comment: Just a reminder that Android 6+ is somewhat beyond the abilities of the hardware of S3 family, be it the Exynos or Snapdragon variant. It's overall usable, but micro-stutters happen very often, due to the SoC's lack of power and the wear-out of the eMMC chip.

Comment: @esQmo_ "opinion based" - Do you feel like a wizard? I am not. We are not speaking about wizardry here. We are speaking about software/hardware engineering, right? Concrete example: other operating systems are shipped with a WELL DEFINED list of "minimum hardware requirements" parameters. It seems that Android also has some compatibility tests ( https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/ ) but I am not an Android savvy so I don't really understand how to install those tests on my S3. I don't need opinions, I need facts (am searching for is that "minimum hardware requirements" list)   :)

Comment: Official website is awful quite about hardware requirements. No wonder so much voodoo and wizardry around Android.  https://source.android.com/source/requirements#hardware-requirements

Comment: @FreeAndNil See? No answer till now. Such questions don't get much attention! But anyway, I think I have answered the question on whether you should install or not.

Comment: It is also super ODD that such a basic information is missing from Android official web site. Android always seemed to me an infant OS (but promising). This actually confirms it.

Comment: "Such questions don't get much attention" - The question was awarded "Notable question" with 3K views. If this question helped 3000 people in the world, then it is something!! PS: Remember it is a question! not a popularity contest!

Comment: The problem is not really about hardware requirements since [Android can even run on Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-android-lineageos/) (the link you mentioned is about hardware requirements for the PC host to build the OS). The problem is more about finding someone who can create/port a ROM with the later Android version for the specific device, since there's no single universal ROM that can be flashed to all Android devices. Follow [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/index-galaxy-s3-roms-kernels-mods-guides.2218825/) for more updated info regarding custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android 7 can be installed on S3:
http://wccftech.com/update-galaxy-s3-to-android-7-1